# keys vs values performance

Tags: perl, hash

I would like to know theoretical background of hash values performing better than keys, and whether perldoc covers this topic.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my %hash = 1 .. 30_000;

cmpthese(-3, {
  values => sub {
    for my $v (values %hash) { }

  },
  keys => sub {
    for my $v (keys %hash) { }
  },
  avalues => sub {
    for my $v (@{[ values %hash ]}) { }
  },
  akeys => sub {
    for my $v (@{[ keys %hash ]}) { }
  },
});

__DATA__
         Rate   akeys    keys avalues  values
akeys   196/s      --    -33%    -56%    -71%
keys    294/s     50%      --    -35%    -57%
avalues 451/s    130%     54%      --    -33%
values  677/s    245%    131%     50%      --
```

perl is 5.20.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The keys aren't stored in the hash as scalar. A string scalar must therefore be created for each key returned by `keys`.

On the other hand, the values are stored as scalars in the hash, and those very scalars are returned by `values`. Nothing copied but a pointer.

---

The above can be demonstrated using using the following benchmark:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark qw( cmpthese );

my %sm_hash = map {                    sprintf('%04d', $_) } 1 .. 1000*2;
my %lg_hash = map { ( "x" x 10_000 ) . sprintf('%04d', $_) } 1 .. 1000*2;

cmpthese(-3, {
   sm_values => sub { 1 for values %sm_hash },
   lg_values => sub { 1 for values %lg_hash },
   sm_keys   => sub { 1 for keys   %sm_hash },
   lg_keys   => sub { 1 for keys   %lg_hash },
});
```

Output:

```
             Rate   lg_keys   sm_keys lg_values sm_values
lg_keys    5286/s        --      -19%      -57%      -58%
sm_keys    6532/s   ==> 24%        --      -47%      -48%
lg_values 12247/s      132%       87%        --       -2%
sm_values 12517/s      137%       92%    ==> 2%        --
```

As you can see, then length of the keys has an effect on how long it takes for `keys` to be evaluated, but the length of the values has no effect on how long it takes for `values` to be evaluated.

---

A simpler but less definitive demonstration comes in the form of an attempt to modify the values returned by `keys` and `values`.

```
for (keys(%h)) {
   $_ = uc($_);  # Has no effect on the hash.
}

for (values(%h)) {
   $_ = uc($_);  # Effects the hash.
}
```